# Can I substitute bread flour for AP flour in banana bread recipe?

Tags: substitutions, bread, bananas

I have bread flour (King Arthur) at home all the time, but I don't usually have all-purpose flour, as bread is pretty much the only thing I bake from scratch. I want to make basic banana bread following [this recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/20144/banana-banana-bread/). I have never made banana bread before.

Can I substitute bread flour for the all-purpose flour? I also have stone-ground whole-wheat flour that I use for chapatis. Would some mixture of whole-wheat and bread flour be a better substitute? The reviews for the banana bread recipe say that it results in a dense loaf, so would using bread flour make it even more dense and thereby unappetizing?

I don't particularly want to keep all-purpose flour on hand in addition to bread flour and whole wheat flour, as my pantry has tons of flours already; ten at last count. I searched online and on this site but the questions typically seem to be about [subbing AP flour for bread flour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10665/baking-bread-with-all-purpose-flour/10669#10669), or [using some other flour instead of wheat flour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21769/how-much-alternative-flour-can-i-substitute-for-white-wheat-flour/21970). I was unable to find anything specifically about using bread flour instead of AP flour.

---

**Update** I decided to risk replacing 1/3 cup of the bread flour with rice flour. I thought that since rice flour is lighter and has no gluten, it would offset the increased denseness caused by using a high-gluten flour. The banana bread turned out fine.

I have posted a [follow-up question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/78493/using-maida-bread-flour-to-create-ap-flour-substitute) about using maida in combination with bread flour to create an all-purpose flour substitute.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it.   If you do, only barely mix it, as you don't want to develop too much gluten or you'll get tunneling.  see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/1729/67

Comment: Bread flour is **more** dense... why would it give a lighter texture? Flour is rated by its protein content - cake flour is the lowest, AP in the middle and bread flour the highest.

Comment: @Catija oh yeah, good point. I forgot that it's the yeast interacting with the gluten that causes bread to rise, not just the high gluten flour by itself. Edited the question.

Comment: It could end up lighter when there is more lift due to more developed gluten that can take advantage of the leavening... but then, you are far into bread-bread, not banana bread territory....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some precautions in your mixing method, you could substitute Bread Flour for AP Flour in Banana Bread. Mind you, it may make a stronger, more dense, more chewy banana bread than people expect--but it would still be pallatable, some may even prefer it.

As discussion here points out: the main concern in the substitution is the higher gluten of bread flour.

I checked the King Arthur website, found that this [bread flour](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/shop/items/king-arthur-unbleached-bread-flour-5-lb) is 12.7% protein (gluten). According to this chart from [Cooking for Geeks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491928050) (I am not affiliated with the book) indicates, this is low-to-average for gluten in bread flours:

[image]
Not over-mixing is critical in this situation, since mixing forms gluten. I can't describe better than @Sam Ley did [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21726/21367). Sam makes a great point: *you should be comfortable leaving some dry clumps in the batter*.

Also, if tempted to sift the flour, I would hesitate. sifting the flour will increase powder surface area, which would facilitate more gluten formation.